# How to create Grunt Multitask to process my templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am using Gruntjs to process templates for my Joomla! extensions.

I have 3 directories and a Grunt file inside my main directory: `component`, `tmpl`, `tasks` and `Gruntfile.js`.

Inside the `tasks` directory I have a file named `compile.js`:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
    grunt.registerMultiTask('compile', 'Compiles Joomla! extension templates', function() {

        // Iterate over all specified file groups.
        this.files.forEach(function(file) {

            var template, phpcode;

            var src = file.src;
            var dest = file.dest;

            if (!grunt.file.exists(src)) {
                grunt.log.warn('Source file "' + src + '" not found.');
                return false;
            }

            template = grunt.file.read(src);
            phpcode = grunt.template.process(template);

            // Write the destination file.
            grunt.file.write(dest, phpcode);

            // Print a success message.
            grunt.log.writeln('File "' + dest + '" created.');
        });
    });
};
```

My Gruntfile has the following code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    compile: {
        model: {          
            files: [
                {src: 'tmpl/model.tmpl', dest: 'component/models/user.php'},
                {src: 'tmpl/model.tmpl', dest: 'component/models/company.php'}
            ]
        }
    }
  });

  // Actually load this plugin's task.
  grunt.loadTasks('tasks');

  grunt.registerTask('compile', ['compile']);
};
```

When I run the command `grunt compile`

```
node.js:893
    var fn = runInThisContext(source, this.filename, true);
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at createWritableStdioStream (node.js:555:18)
    at process.stdout (node.js:612:16)
    at write (/home/qawe/Desktop/code/compile/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/log.js:78:12)
    at writeln (/home/qawe/Desktop/code/compile/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/log.js:85:3)
    at Object.log.writeln (/home/qawe/Desktop/code/compile/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/log.js:96:3)
    at writeln (/home/qawe/Desktop/code/compile/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/fail.js:39:13)
    at Object.fail.fatal (/home/qawe/Desktop/code/compile/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/fail.js:55:3)
    at process.uncaughtHandler (/home/qawe/Desktop/code/compile/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:123:10)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at process._fatalException (node.js:272:26)
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Please help, I'm  still a newbie in Grunt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling is that you overwrote the task name by defining compile twice. I tested your code using the default task and got this:

```
$ grunt
Running "compile:model" (compile) task
Warning: Arguments to path.join must be strings Use --force to continue.
```

You're passing an array in `var src`, you may want to iterate over those if you want to pass in an array to your custom function. Otherwise if you're just using the one path, do `var src = file.src.toString();`.

Then change your registerTask to use a different name and you should be all set:

```
grunt.registerTask('docompile', ['compile']);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben you are a life saver, but I don't understand why src is an array while dest is a string. In my Grantfile they are defined the same way.

Comment: I think it has something to do with how Grunt processes the src/dest mappings: the usual pattern is one/many infiles, one outfile (concat is basically built in).